# What fields are required in a triggered send data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

newbie here to SFMC. I am trying to trigger an email send using below endpoint and payload

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:external_key/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

Which of these fields from my payload do I need add to my triggered send data extension on SFMC? Is it just Region, City and State? Do I also need FromAddress, FromName or SubscriberKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only two fields that are required by the system, and the Subscriber Key and Email Address. The rest is up to you, so you get to decide if you want to include the Region, City, State, etc.

It can be useful for tracking and logging sent content to include all dynamic fields in your TSDE, but they are not required by the system.

[image]